# bdd via cucumber-js on windows,tons of issues! anyone achieved yet?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd

i  have been facing serious trouble in making work cucumber-js in windows.

i start thinking does it worth it, the time i have spent with installing node.js and cucumber.

well i installed node.js from .msi file. it went ok.

I installed cucumber via locally from package.json

the node_modules folder has been created under my project folder.

there is a file within folder name .bin called cucumber.js

so when i tap that file via command line i got a scrip error saying character error

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -x "`dirname "$0"`/node" ]; then
  "`dirname "$0"`/node"  "`dirname "$0"`/./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "`dirname "$0"`/./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret



#!/bin/sh this shebang did not recognized and gives script error. is this thing pythonish thing? should i install python.
```

is there anyone who has used cucumber-js for bdd for javascript? is there any other frameworks where i could continue leverage my gherkin files which i already written for specflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug and will be fixed by [#60](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/60).

Comment: thanks, julien. sorry for duplication it was in during my desperate feltdown. :)